# What sort of page weight / size should I be aiming for when optimising for mobile?

Tags: jquery, optimization, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm looking to optimise the mobile browser experience in a small webapp, using the awesome jQuery mobile to do so.

It goes without saying that a user doesn't want to DL 200k of data, I'm just trying to draw the line between using external and internal URLs. Is there any existing guideline of what sort of page sizes / loading times I should be shooting for? I'd prefer to stick to internal URLs (keep the mobile interface effectively in one place from a maintenance point of view), but am weary of bogging the user down with lots of information that they have no intention of viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that e.g. [iPhone won't cache components bigger than 25K](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/02/06/iphone-cacheability/).

Also consider [minifing](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) and gzipping your code. And *@jfar* got one thing right. HTTP requests can be a huge performance hit, so you may also want to reduce them as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Much more important is to not be chatty between server and client. The delay can be large, and makes it sensible to pack more together than you would do normally. Validating on the server after each keypress would be painfull.

Comment: So does this point more to the 'internal links' model where you get more data at first, staying away from population-through-ajax?

Comment: Sounds like... I think that's the main key, send as much as you can, but only what you need as little as possible.

Does raise an issue with library's such as jquery and having to reload them each page, perhaps crafty DHTML can help out there.

Answer (score 1):

Size doesn't matter.  Download times does.

Mobile speeds differ every hundred feet in some areas so its not like some xxxk amount is going to always be perfect.

Go for "as small as possible".

Comment: I do appreciate the sentiment, however it can hardly be denied that page size affects loading times - I'm not looking for perfect, but rather some kind of metric that should be small enough for as many people as possible.

Comment: @Simon Scarfe - I think you're missing the point.  Of course size effects overall download duration but the completely variable nature of phone speeds is going to make it impossible to create a great experience for everybody.  200k is almost nothing to somebody on 4g but sucks really badly for the mobile service I get.

Comment: Be sure to compress/zip content if supported too. This can greatly reduce size.

Answer (score 1):

According to the W3C [Mobile Web Best Practices](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/):

- size of page markup < 10 kilobyte
- size of page including images < 20 kilobyte

Answer (score 0):

I would say try to lower your page as much to 100kb, because if u manage to do so loading different pages as per user request **might** be negligible.

However, loading the big pile of content at a time and using simple javascript show and hide, to display the content in almost realtime manner might impress the viewer too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look into the HTML5 Cache Manifest specification, it allows you to define a set of resources the browser should keep offline. It's like the old fashioned Browser cache but better because it's controllable.

For mobile websites size does matter, but what matters much more are the number of requests the browser has to do. Inline as much of your images in the css files as you can, because every request takes time (in my experience up to 4000ms ping!) consolidate all javascript into one file and send all things gzip compressed.

If you want to get a feeling for what matters in mobile development take out your calculator and calculate the loading times. Make up 500ms for each request and take about 8-20 KiB/s for loading time into consideration. That's not the worst case but it's not the best case too.